# What do gekko's sign3 and abs3 return?

Tags: conditional-statements, gekko

I have a variable that I want to be either 1 or 0 based on the sign of an intermediate. I could use sign2 which returns 1 or -1 based on the sign and do operations to turn it to 0 or 1. However, when I was exploring, I noticed a sign3 and abs3 which included a binary variable with the signum/absolute value. Do these functions return a list like [signum/absolute value, 0/1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GEKKO functions `sign2` and `sign3` return the same type of output, either `-1` or `1` depending on the sign of the variable they are applied to. The difference between them is how the signum (sign) operation is accomplished. Both implementations are continuously differentiable and thus suitable for gradient-based optimization.

The `sign2` function uses an [MPCC](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/MpecExamples) [formulation](http://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions) to generate the sign of an argument, and can be used with any of the solvers. The `sign3` function uses a binary switching variable and the MINLP solver [APOPT](https://apopt.com/).